# Reading numbers and characters from a file

Tags: c, file

I'm having some trouble with in files.

I'm attempting to read in numbers and special characters from a file. I'm given a file that contains numbers and operands. The file is read in from the command line.

Sample file:

```
 1 4 + 5* 
 2 - 4 + 8
 7 -2 +1 +3
 0
```

So the file is terminated with 0 and each new line is an expression. What my code is attempting to do is read in one expression at a time

```
1 4 + 5 *
```

Work with it, then move on to the next expression (until the file reads 0). It need to contain the special characters as well (+, *, -, ect)

This is my code so far. I don't know the length of each expression (it can vary) so I just statically declared it as a length of 50.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){


    FILE* input;
    char expression[50];
    int i;
    char ch;


    input = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if(input == NULL){
        printf("File does not exist! Exiting program!");
        return 0;
    }

    do{
        ch= fgetc(input);
        if(ch == 0)
             break;

         while((ch != '\n')){
         //printf("test2\n");
             expression[i] = ch;
             i++;
             ch = fgetc(input);
         }

    //plan to do something with each expression here
    } while(ch != EOF); 


    for(i=0; i < (strlen(expression)); i++)
         printf("%c ", expression[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

All I'm trying to do here is just check to see if it will read in the expressions and print them out correctly. When I try to run it I get a segfault, I put in the test2 statement to test and it prints it out(infinite loop) until it seg faults.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your inner `while` loop runs until segfault because you never update `ch`. You forgot to set it to the output of `fgetc`. In addition, you should also check if `fgetc` returns 0.

Comment: 1) `char expression[50];` (for null-terminate) --> `char expression[50] = {0};` 2) `char ch;` (for EOF) --> `int  ch;` 3) `if(ch == 0)` --> `if(ch == '0')` (?) 4)  `i++; fgetc(input);` --> `i++; ch = fgetc(input);`

Comment: I added the update to ch and it's still in the infinite loop

Comment: Change: `if(ch == 0)` to `if(ch == '0')`

Comment: Minor: `char ch;` should be`int ch;`

Answer (score 0):

For your kind of file have:

```
while((ch=fgetc(input)) != '0' )
  {
  /* your main processing */
  if (ch == '\n')
    {
    /* deal with end of expression */
    }

  }
```

Having multiple **while** blocks and **fgetc(input);** is confusing for everyone.

Comment: I'm attempting to do it this way, however ch=fgetc(input) is getting the whole expression at once rather then one character at a time.